# How to visit method invocation in newest version of Android Lint

Tags: java, android, lint

I am writing a new Android lint rule which need to visit all method invocations and then it analyzes annotation of each method to decide handling. However, I am getting trouble which very first step: **visit all method invocations**.

In conclusion, all I want is that when I have the code below, the 2 final lines (*test.testMethod();* and *testMethod();*) are highlighted as error by Android Studio.

```
    public class MyClass {
        class TestClass {
            void testMethod() {}
        }

        void testMethod() {}

        void testCall() {
            TestClass test = new TestClass();
            test.testMethod(); // expect highlight
            testMethod(); // expect highlight
        }
    }
```

In the old version of lint framework I think I can achieve this by:

```
public class MyDetector extends Detector implements Detector.JavaScanner {

    @Override
    public
    List<Class<? extends Node>> getApplicableNodeTypes() {
        //noinspection unchecked
        return Arrays.<Class<? extends Node>>asList(MethodInvocation.class);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public AstVisitor createJavaVisitor(@NonNull JavaContext context) {
        return new CallVisitor(context);
    }

    private class CallVisitor extends ForwardingAstVisitor {
        private final JavaContext mContext;

        public CallVisitor(JavaContext context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean visitMethodInvocation(@NonNull MethodInvocation call) {
            String message = "Nguyen Ha Quang";
            mContext.report(THREAD, call, mContext.getLocation(call), message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

*This code is referenced from https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:tools/base/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/SupportAnnotationDetector.java;bpv=0 (line 1516 -> end).*

Unfortunately, since AndroidX was released, this code is no longer work. Now, I must try to do something like this:

```
public class ChatWorkerDetector extends Detector implements Detector.UastScanner {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends UElement>> getApplicableUastTypes() {
        return Arrays.<Class<? extends UElement>>asList(
                UCallableReferenceExpression.class
        );
    }

    @Override
    public UElementHandler createUastHandler(JavaContext context) {
        return new CustomElementHandler(context);
    }

    public class CustomElementHandler extends UElementHandler {
        JavaContext mContext;

        public CustomElementHandler(JavaContext mContext) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
        }

        @Override
        public void visitCallableReferenceExpression(UCallableReferenceExpression node) {
            String message = "Nguyen Ha Quang";
            mContext.report(THREAD, node, mContext.getLocation(node), message);
        }
    }
}
```

This code still does not work as I expect and I also have tried: visitCallableReferenceExpression, visitMethod, visitCallExpression, but none of them work.

**Is any visitABC function available in UElementHandler class which can do my job?**

*UElementHandler source code: https://github.com/ouyangpeng/android-lint-checks-studio3.0/blob/master/libs/lint-api/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/client/api/UElementHandler.java*

Thank you very much.